# Vue variables disappearing between methods

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have been working with Vue for a couple of months now and I have run into an error I cannot comprehend. My data variables are "disappearing" between methods. 
I am working on an Laravel app that allows a user to enter an origin, destination and a number of waypoints, if the route is valid I then obtain the elevation data for that route . I use the Google Maps API to compute the route and I then compile an object containing the GPS co-ordinates which describe the length of the route.

I then use this object in a second method to retrieve the elevation data. The reason for the second method is that I call it form a second button.

```
<script>
import { loadedGoogleMapsAPI } from "./GoogleMapsApiLoader";

export default {
  mounted() {
    loadedGoogleMapsAPI.then(() => {
      this.initMap();
    });
  },

  data() {
    return {
      mapOptions: {},
      map: null,
      co_ords: {},
      origin_input: null,
      destination_input: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    initMap() {
      this.mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: -28.4792625, lng: 24.6727135 },
        mapTypeId: "terrain"
      };
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"),
        this.mapOptions
      );
    },

    directions() {
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

      directionsService.route(
        {
          origin: this.origin_input,
          destination: this.destination_input,
          travelMode: "DRIVING"
        },
        function(response, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            \\Do some processing to get the GPS co-ords

            this.co_ords = list_of_gps_data; \\Set the global variable equal to the object containing the lat & long data
            console.log(this.co_ords); \\this displays perfectly
          } else {
            window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
          }
        }
      );

    },

    elevation() {
      console.log(this.co_ords);

    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The output of the first `console.log(this.co_ords)`:

```
0: Object { latitude: "-29.11462", longitude: "23.75092" }
​​
1: Object { latitude: "-29.11449", longitude: "23.75119" }
​​
2: Object { latitude: "-29.11433", longitude: "23.75146" }
​​
3: Object { latitude: "-29.11419", longitude: "23.75165" }
​​
4: Object { latitude: "-29.11407", longitude: "23.75179" }
```

The output of the `console.log(this.co_ords)` in the second method:

```
__ob__: {…}
​​
dep: Object { id: 12, subs: [] }
​​
value: {…}
​​​
__ob__: {…}
​​​​
dep: Object { id: 12, subs: [] }
​​​​
value: Object { … }
​​​​
vmCount: 0
```

If i use the Vue debugger for Firefox to view the variables, the debug window never updates the variable, the variable value remains null:

```
co_ords:Object (empty)
```

What am I doing wrong, where is the object disappearing to? I have spent hours trying to find it, I have read and reread the Vue documentation, the Laravel documentation, I have tried defining the variable with a different name, I cannot explain it.

Comment: `co_ords` property is set on wrong object. `function(response, status)` should be an arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are both creating and logging `this.co_ords` from inside of a function callback.  `this` refers to the callback function context, not the Vue instance.  The `co_ords` in the Vue instance is never set.

If you use an es6 arrow function instead, it will work as expected.  Change:

```
function(response, status) {
```

to

```
(response, status) => {
```

Here is a simplified [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/5fom478n/) you can check out.